# javax json toString still returns memory value

Tags: java, json, java-7, tostring

I am trying to pipe the stanford-nlp output to json. I tried with the simple-json and everything works fine. When I try to use the javax.json as shown below

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            JsonObjectBuilder parserJSONObj = stanfordNLPParser(processedQuestion);
            System.out.println(parserJSONObj.toString());

        }       

    public static JsonObjectBuilder stanfordNLPParser (String processedQuestion)throws IOException {

            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, sentiment");
            StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

            JsonObjectBuilder parserJSONObj = Json.createObjectBuilder(); 


            Annotation annotation = pipeline.process(processedQuestion);
            List<CoreMap> sentences = annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);
            for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {        
                for (CoreMap quesGentokens : sentence.get(TokensAnnotation.class)) {
                    String quesGenToken = quesGentokens.toString();
                    String quesGenPOS = quesGentokens.get(PartOfSpeechAnnotation.class);

                            parserJSONObj.add(quesGenToken, Json.createArrayBuilder()
                            .add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
                            .add("POS", quesGenPOS)));

                            parserJSONObj.build();              
                            System.out.println(parserJSONObj.toString());
                }

            }
            return parserJSONObj;           
        }
```

output:

```
org.glassfish.json.JsonObjectBuilderImpl@6eb82908
```

I have few questions on this now:

1. even adding toString only shows the memory location.
2. is the return type JsonObjectBuilder right return type (Considering, further operations on the Json).

Thanks

Comment: You are printing the builder, not the JSON object that the builder created.

Answer (score 0):

I think You should return `JsonObject` from this method.
You can get `JsonObject` by using:

```
JsonObject json = parserJSONObj.build();
```

If you do `toString()` on this json, you will get actual JSON printed on your console.